# Run make command on GIT in windows

Tags: android, git, mupdf

I am compiling MuPDF Library through GIT and NDK but failed to run command as `make generate`. Please suggest any solution regarding running `make` command on GIT in windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi @Pietu1998, the error before running make command is gen_cmap_cns.h no such file or directory. I searched it on Web then some body says that first run make command on MuPDF library then the problem will solved.

Comment: Googling "windows make" found this toolkit, that contains make for Windows. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

Comment: Git for Windows does not provide *make*. It provides Git. Nothing else. If you need a build environment for Windows, you should be installing msys or cygwin.